# Не возвращается частичное представление

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Страница с формой. 
        
    ..

Под ней выводится частичное представление:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="results">
            @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_DataTable", Model);}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Содержимое частичного представления, т.е функция вызова находится в самом частичном представлении, мне кажется это не должно ни на что влиять.

```
  @foreach (ThermLossesDataInputWaterPipeline item in Model.listThermLossesDataInputWaterPipelines)
        {
         <tr class="row_@item.ThermLossesDataInputWaterPipelineId">
            ..
              <td>@item.DeepLying</td>
            ..
              <td>
                  <button onclick="Edit(this);" id="@item.ThermLossesDataInputWaterPipelineId"></button>
              </td>
        </tr>
        }
```

По `onclick="Edit(this);`" выполняется следующий `AJAX` вот тут, `alert`  не возвращает `"OK"`. Т.е. скрипт выполняется, а `success` нет.

```
 function Edit(obj) {
            if (confirm('Вы хотите изменить данные на новые (заполненные) значения?')) {
                var thermLossesDataInputWaterPipelineId = obj.id;
                var lyingTypeOne = $('#lyingTypeOne').val();
                var lyingTypeTwo = $('#lyingTypeTwo').val();
                var insulation = $('#insulation').val();
                var commissioning = $('#commissioning').val();
                var countPlumbing = $('#countPlumbing').val();
                var outsideDiametr = $('#outsideDiametr').val();
                var longSection = $('#longSection').val();
                var deepLying = $('#deepLying').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data: {
                        LyingTypeOne: lyingTypeOne, LyingTypeTwo: lyingTypeTwo,
                        Insulation: insulation, Commissioning: commissioning, CountPlumbing: countPlumbing, OutsideDiametr: outsideDiametr,
                        LongSection: longSection, DeepLying: deepLying, update: true, ThermLossesDataInputWaterPipelineId: thermLossesDataInputWaterPipelineId
                    },
                    url: '@Url.Action("SaveDataInputWaterPipelines", "ThermLosses", new { ViewBag.ThermLossesObjectDataInputId })',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("OK");
                        $('#results').html(data);
                    }
                });
            } else false;
        }
```

Все это приходит на контроллер:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult SaveDataInputWaterPipelines(int ThermLossesObjectDataInputId, string LyingTypeOne, string LyingTypeTwo,
            string Insulation, string Commissioning, string CountPlumbing, string OutsideDiametr, string LongSection, string DeepLying,
            bool update, int ThermLossesDataInputWaterPipelineId)
        {
             ...
            WaterPipelineViewModel model = new WaterPipelineViewModel();
            model.listThermLossesDataInputWaterPipelines = _context.ThermLossesDataInputWaterPipelines.Where(m => m.ThermLossesObjectDataInputId == ThermLossesObjectDataInputId).ToList();
            return PartialView("_DataTable", model);
       }
```

Консоль, если я все правильно понял, то метод отправил данные. Почему `Ajax` не обновляет данные? Если обновить страницу через F5, данные изменяться. Тут или дело в `Ajax` *(скорее всего)* или в самом частичном представлении. Что я делаю не так?

[image: Консоль]

Comment: [убрал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/336922) излишнее форматирование см: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328/ (Пожалуйста, не злоупотребляйте внутристрочным форматированием. Не стоит раскрашивать вопросы-ответы излишним форматированием)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я удалил `dataType: 'JSON' это решило мою проблему.

> dataType:string(определяется автоматически (xml, json, script, или
>   html)) Тип данных, в котором **ожидается получить ответ от сервера**. Если
>   он не задан, jQuery попытается определить его автоматически с помощью
>   полученного от сервера MIME.

[Еще ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51114427/cant-update-partial-view-with-ajax-asp-net-core-mvc)